# How do I import sketchpy-mob

Tags: pydroid

I tried importing sketchpy-mob on my android tablet on pydroid 3 but it keeps saying syntaxes error I tried up everything I could but u still find a answer I even tried renaming it but said their is no module named sketchpy-mob but it is in my module download library
I tried everything I can think and looked up everything I can find but nothing helps